# Is it possible to get databases on pgadmin4 after a windows reset (keep files option)?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is it possible to get databases on pgadmin4 after a windows reset (keep files option) ? I do not have files with pg_dump. The directory was default. Thank you.

Comment: Is the data directory still there? Then no problem. Is the data directory gone? No way.

Comment: Thank you... I thought so... Given that I lost 6 months of research it really stings... Is it possible to set automated backup on pgadmin ?

Comment: I don't think that pgAdmin is the right tool for backups. My first advice would be to put the database on a different disk from the operating system. I know that the Windows installer suggests a subdirectory of the software directory, which is a bad place. If your data are important, you need a backup strategy. At the very least you have learned something.

Comment: Yeah, I can see that now. Thank you so much, I certainly learned a lot. Also, turns out I also kept the data as json files and those were not deleted so it somehow worked out! :)

Comment: I am happy to hear that.